# MVC actionlink posting List of complex type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have an actionlink that on click im passing a List of objects to a controller action.

Example:

View:

```
Html.ActionLink("TestLink", "TestMethod", "Test", Model.SampleList, null)
```

TestController:

```
public ActionResult TestMethod(List<SampleList> sampleList)  
{  
  return View(sampleList);  
}
```

When I do this I get a null sampleList.  I can pass a single complex object fine just not a collection of it.  Do I need the correct routing for this?  The reason I'm doing this is instead of passing an id and do a look up in the controller action, I just pass in the data.

Comment: Thats not going to work.  This code is attempting to create a URL that contains the public properties of `Model.SampleList` as query string parameters.  You can verify this by looking at the URL that is generated in the browser.

Comment: Yes, I did verify that I thought actionlink was gonna be smart enough to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible when you perform a form post, have a look at [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) for more information.  You'll probably not be able to use one of the HtmlHelper methods though, the post states:

> Currently, we don’t have any helpers
>   for generating the form, so this is a
>   very manual process.

Nothing prevents you from writing your own helper though.

Comment: Wow, you basically have to bind the model list to a form and post it.  Cool thanks this explains it all.